# Simplify xml to json conversion

Tags: c#, json, xml

I'm looking for a easy way to convert my xml to json with the additional option to add the full xpath as attribute. Now I do it this way:

```
  private static string XmlToJson(string xmlString)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(GetXmlValues(XElement.Parse(xmlString)));
        }

        private static Dictionary<string, object> GetXmlValues(XElement xml)
        {
            var attr = xml.Attributes().ToDictionary(d => d.Name.LocalName, d => (object)d.Value);
            if (xml.HasElements)
            {
                attr.Add("_children", xml.Elements().Select(e => GetXmlValues(e)));
                attr.Add("_path", xml.GetPath());
            }
            else if (!xml.IsEmpty)
            {
                attr.Add("_value", xml.Value);
               attr.Add("_path", xml.GetPath());
            }
            return new Dictionary<string, object> { { xml.Name.LocalName, attr } };
        }

       private static string GetPath(this XElement node)
        {
            string path = node.Name.LocalName;
            XElement currentNode = node;
            while (currentNode.Parent != null)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.Parent;
                path = currentNode.Name.LocalName + "/" + path;
            }
            return path;
        }
```

But it looks circuitous compare to:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
```

But there for I have no idea how to add the path during the convertion?

Comment: You aren't converting from XML to Json, you create a completely different representation with `_value` and `_path` attributes that hold ... something. Please post examples of the source XML and desired JSon output. If you want to serialize a different shape, perform the transformation in an intermediate step (eg using LINQ) then serialize the result

Answer (score 0):

> But it looks circuitous compare to

Json.net uses it's own implementation of [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) named  [`XmlNodeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_converters_xmlnodeconverter.htm). So if you want it to look not circuitous, you can implement [your own JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and use it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, new MyXmlWithXPathJsonConverter());
```

This is a nice but quite complex task.

But a bit simpler way is to append your xml nodes with xpath attribute right before serialization. For example:

```
public void AppendXPath(XContainer container)
{
    if (container == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

    var doc = container as XDocument;
    if (doc != null)
        AppendXPath(doc.Root, "", 1);
    else
        AppendXPath(container as XElement, "/", 1);
}

private void AppendXPath(XElement node, string parent, int num)
{
    var path = $"{parent}/{node.Name}[{num}]";

    if (node.Attribute("xpath") != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Node {path} already contains xpath attribute");

    var indicies = new Dictionary<XName, int>();

    foreach (var child in node.Elements())
    {
        int index;
        if (indicies.TryGetValue(child.Name, out index))
            indicies[child.Name] = ++index;
        else
            indicies[child.Name] = index = 1;

        AppendXPath(child, path, index);
    }

    node.Add(new XAttribute("xpath", path));
}
```

Test:

```
void Test()
{
    var xml =
@"<xml>
    <foo>
        <one />
        <other />
    </foo>
    <bar data=""abc"">
        <item order=""3"" />
        <item order=""1"">
            <child whatever="""" />
        </item>
    </bar>
</xml>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    AppendXPath(doc);
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "xml": {
    "@xpath": "/xml[1]",
    "foo": {
      "@xpath": "/xml[1]/foo[1]",
      "one": {
        "@xpath": "/xml[1]/foo[1]/one[1]"
      },
      "other": {
        "@xpath": "/xml[1]/foo[1]/other[1]"
      }
    },
    "bar": {
      "@data": "abc",
      "@xpath": "/xml[1]/bar[1]",
      "item": [
        {
          "@order": "3",
          "@xpath": "/xml[1]/bar[1]/item[1]"
        },
        {
          "@order": "1",
          "@xpath": "/xml[1]/bar[1]/item[2]",
          "child": {
            "@whatever": "",
            "@xpath": "/xml[1]/bar[1]/item[2]/child[1]"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```